# From a jailbreaked iPhone 3g 4.1 (foreign sim locked) to 4.2

Tags: jailbreak, iphone, ios, sim

A friend of mine bought an iPhone 3g with a sim card in another country. Some months ago he gave me this iPhone, but he forgot to give me the sim too, so I've jailbreaked it leaving the sim-lock, that is I don't use this iphone for the phone calls.

So now I have a jailbreaked iPhone 3G with iOS 4.1 and I would to pass to iOS 4.2

How should I do? If I simply upgrade from iTunes, will it ask me for active sim card?

Moreover, I've read that if there is a problem, it is no possible to downgrade to 4.1, isn't it?

**EDIT**

I've the baseband 05.14.02 and bootloader 5.9

I'm not interested to use this iphone for phone calls, but I would maintain the gps.

Is it possible to pass to 4.2.1 maintaining the baseband 05.14.02?

Comment: Have you tried @Gesher links?

Comment: Yes. I'm a little confused by the step two. "Step Two
***If you are already on iOS 4.2.1 you can skip this step. If you are on an unlockable baseband and on a lower firmware you should use PwnageTool instead to update without upgrading your baseband." My baseband isn't unlockable, but I don't worry about it. So, it seems that I can follow completely this guide without choosing the baseband upgrade when it is prompted (and without using PwnageTool), doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac: http://iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=12947

Windows: http://iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=12949